What's the white substance spread across this thermal fuse and these two resistors?
The thermal fuse on this bed warmer controller tripped and I'm planning on replacing it. It's the one between the two fat resistors in the center of the board with longer axial leads.
Why does it have a sticky and powdery white substance spread across it and the two resistors that it is sandwiched in between? Is it a kind of thermal paste used to dissipate heat? If so, can I use normal thermal paste (like Arctic Silver or something) to replace it?


thermal paste used to dissipate heat ... no ... thermal paste is used to conduct heat ... a heatsink is used to dissipate heat

I meant dissipate across the resistors, of course. I realize now the opposite is more likely, conducting the heat of the resistors into the thermal fuse.

Probably some thermally conductive paste to make sure the thermal fuse is responsive to the temperature of the resistors. If it seems like it is cured like glue it may also be a form of staking compound to help physically secure the components. I would be wary of replacing it with CPU thermal compound as it is designed to thin out with heat iirc.
If the thermal fuse has tripped, just replacing it may not fix the problem as there was a reason it tripped in the first place. And since this is going into a piece of heat producing equipment that you will be lying on while you sleep it may be best to just get a new controller entirely.

Yes, I think I know why it tripped. The substance is definitely not used for securing anything, it has the consistency of cheese mold, so structurally pretty useless.
